# Is it 'better' to use mysql_dsn rather than mysql_ram_disk with buildkit and amp config?

Tags: mysql, civicrm-buildkit

I've successfully set up a `drupal-clean` test build on my Ubuntu 19.04 machine using buildkit, `amp config` and `amp test` and chose `mysql_ram_disk` rather than `mysql_dsn`.

My intent was to have a semi-permanent dev environment.

Did I make the wrong choice? Should I use `mysql_ram_disk` for such an environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to answer without more info but generally the ram disk isn't going to save your data unless you do something extra, so it's more useful for one-off tests or something where you need speed over permanence, like running unit tests (which it mentions in the [readme](https://github.com/amp-cli/amp/blob/v0.5.0/doc/ramdisk.md)). I don't use buildkit since I'm on windows but I do [switch over to a ramdisk](https://gist.github.com/demeritcowboy/9631bc0114594be10a7a75ae766baca4) when running tests since it's way faster when it keeps needing to load/reset the database. I wouldn't recommend a ramdisk for setting up a semi-permanent dev environment that you plan to work on regularly, unless you're willing to regularly dump the data somewhere and reload it later, or automate that at startup/shutdown, and risk losing something in the middle.

Comment: right so the ram_disk is loaded into ram and disappears when I shut my machine down. Duh on me. So, I made the wrong choice, since my goal is a semi-permanent dev environment. Back to `amp config` set up. Thanks!

Comment: From the readme - "The data will be wiped after rebooting or unmounting."

Comment: Edited the text to add more info about my intent/goal.